# Android library projects and custom xml attributes

Tags: android, xml-attribute, library-project

I'm using two libraries in my projects: holoeverywhere and google maps v2. Everything works just fine except when I try to use the libraries custom xml-attributes.
Since ADT r17 we no longer have to use the package name to define the namespace, instead we use **"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"**. res-auto is automatically substituted with the package name.
For example if you want to configure the initial state of a google map fragment in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
map:uiCompass="true"
map:mapType= "normal"
map:uiRotateGestures="true"
map:uiScrollGestures="true"
map:uiTiltGestures="true"
map:uiZoomControls="true"
map:uiZoomGestures="true"/>
```

I keep getting an error: **No resource identifier found for attribute 'map' in package ‘res-auto’** 
Same thing happens when I use **xmlns:holo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"**
I cannot access the custom xml attributes of that namepsace!
Now I know you can create a map fragment programatically but I want to find a solution for this. What am I missing? Also i'm targeting apis 10-17!

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At least for Maps V2, you are probably running into [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53283) in the Eclipse tools.